# Is it possible to have a JMS server without an application server?

Tags: java, jms

does anyone here knows if there exists a JMS server that could be executed on Tomcat or without an application server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, several.

- [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) (recommended)
- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) (which I don't recommend, but is popular)

and several others, but those are are the big ones.

Comment: Why not ActiveMQ? (actually, thanks for the tips. I'm trying HornetQ now)

Comment: I've tried using ActiveMQ in versions 3, 4 and 5, and every time I've abandoned it due to being horribly buggy and unstable. I've learned my lesson. Hornet is quite tasty, though, and goes for stability over features.

Answer (score 5):

ActiveMQ comes with [a standalone broker](http://activemq.apache.org/run-broker.html) which can be run independently from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Message Queue (OpenMQ)](https://javaee.github.io/openmq/) is the default JMS broker in the [GlassFish application server](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/).

OpenMQ supports non Java clients and also runs standalone.

The next version (4.4) is about to be released with J2EE 6 and NetBeans 6.8. OpenMQ is ready for production use.

Answer (score 1):

[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) also comes with a standalone broker and features [AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html)